# How do I create a dummy variable by comparing columns in different data frames?

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I would like to compare one column of a df with another column in a different df. The columns are timestamp and holiday date. I'd like to create a dummy variable wherein if the timestamp in df1 match the dates in df2 = 1, else 0.

For example, df1:

```
   timestamp     weight(kg)
0  2016-03-04      4.0
1  2015-02-15      5.0
2  2019-05-04      5.0
3  2018-12-25      29.0
4  2020-01-01      58.0
```

For example, df2:

```
   holiday     
0  2016-12-25      
1  2017-01-01      
2  2019-05-01      
3  2018-12-26      
4  2020-05-26
```

Ideal output:

```
      timestamp     weight(kg)  holiday
0     2016-03-04      4.0         0
1     2015-02-15      5.0         0
2     2019-05-04      5.0         0
3     2018-12-25      29.0        1
4     2020-01-01      58.0        1
```

I have tried writing a function but it is taking very long to calculate:

```
def add_holiday(x):
    hols_df = hols.apply(lambda y: y['holiday_dt'] if 
                                x['timestamp'] == y['holiday_dt']
                                                else None, axis=1)
    hols_df = hols_df.dropna(axis=0, how='all')  
    if hols_df.empty:
        hols_df= np.nan
    else: 
        hols_df= hols_df.to_string(index=False)
        
    return hols_df
    

    
#df_hols['holidays'] = df_hols.apply(add_holiday, axis=1)
```

Perhaps, there is a simpler way to do so or the function is not exactly well-written. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with convert mask to `1,0` by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df1['holiday'] = df1['timestamp'].isin(df2['holiday']).astype(int)
```

Or with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df1['holiday'] = np.where(df1['timestamp'].isin(df2['holiday']), 1, 0)
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response. Have used the np.where suggestion! Out of curiosity, if I were to reset the df1 index to the timestamp, how do I compare df2['holiday'] with df1 timestamp index?

Comment: @mmbbb - then use `df1['holiday'] = np.where(df1.index.isin(df2['holiday']), 1, 0)`